# How to read a string to get user input in GNU Guile?

Tags: scheme, command-line-interface, lisp, user-input, guile

I'm trying to make a Rock Paper Scissors game to help myself lean GNU Guile. I've hit a snag where I get user input, the player's choice in the game. If I set it to a string, then the game works correctly. If I use `(read)` I get back #f as the type from the look up. I've tried formatting read to try to make it a string, which didn't work.

```lisp
(define (print a)
  (display a)
  (newline))

(define choices (make-hash-table 3))
(hashq-set! choices "r" "s")
(hashq-set! choices "s" "p")
(hashq-set! choices "p" "r")

(define (cpu-choice) (list-ref (list "r" "p" "s") (random 3)))

(print "You are playing rock paper scissors.")
(print "Type r for rock, p for paper, and s for scissors.")
(define draw
  ;; "s" ; This works as a test.
 (read (open-input-string (read))) ; Can't get user in as string, so the hashq-ref will work.
  )

(define cpu-draw (cpu-choice))

;; debug
(print (format #f "Player enterd ~a" draw))
(print (format #f "Player needs to with ~a" (hashq-ref choices draw))) ; Keeps coming back as #f
(print (format #f "CPU has entered ~a" cpu-draw))

;; norm
(newline)
(when (eq? draw cpu-draw)
  (print "There was a tie")
  (exit))

(when (eq? (hashq-ref choices draw) cpu-draw)
  (print "You have won.")
  (exit))

(print "You have failed. The computer won.")
```

How do I get a string from the user? Maybe something like `(str (read))` or `(read-string)` (reading as a string).

```sh
$ guile --version
guile (GNU Guile) 2.0.13
```

### Update

I'd just like to mention that while the answer approved is correct, I didn't understand how Guile/Scheme does strings and symbols when writing this. The only way I got the program to work was to change all the strings in `choices` and in the `cpu-choice` list into symbols. Ex:

```lisp
(hashq-set! choices 'r 's)
```

```lisp
(list 'r 'p 's)
```

Thank you Óscar López for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you surround the input with double quotes, the value that you type will be interpreted as a *symbol*. Either try this:

```
(define str (read))
> "hello"
```

Or this:

```
(define str (symbol->string (read)))
> hello
```

Either way, `str` will now hold an actual string:

```
str
=> "hello"
```